# Dataframe sum on column with condition

Tags: python, dataframe, sum

I edited my question to make a simpler example.

I have this DataFrame:

| D | N |
| --- | --- |
| 01/06/2021 | 2 |
| 01/06/2021 | 4 |
| 01/06/2021 | 0 |
| 02/06/2021 | 1 |
| 02/06/2021 | 0 |
| 03/06/2021 | 1 |
| 03/06/2021 | 5 |
| 03/06/2021 | 1 |
| 04/06/2021 | 2 |
| 05/06/2021 | 0 |
| 05/06/2021 | 2 |
| 05/06/2021 | 4 |
| 08/06/2021 | 7 |
| 09/06/2021 | 3 |
| 09/06/2021 | 9 |

How can I get the sum on the N column for each row, where D column in range [D-2,D] days (last 3 days).

This is the expected result:

| D | N |
| --- | --- |
| 01/06/2021 | 6 |
| 02/06/2021 | 7 |
| 03/06/2021 | 14 |
| 04/06/2021 | 10 |
| 05/06/2021 | 15 |
| 08/06/2021 | 7 |
| 09/06/2021 | 19 |

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add what your expected output should look like? Are you just after a number of the sum between those dates? or an added column of the cumsum or something?

Comment: Can you share the first 10 rows of expected results please ?

Comment: @Dodic could you explain how 02/06/2021---7 and 03/06/2021---14 are obtained

Comment: 02/06/2021 is the sum of previous 3 days (01/06/2021; 02/06/2021) = 2+4+0+1+0
03/06/2021 is the sum of previous 3 days (01/06/2021; 02/06/2021; 03/06/2021) = 2+4+0+1+0+1+5+1

Comment: answered below.

Comment: @Dodic all okey?

Answer (score 0):

Column 'D' is converted using pd.to_datetime. The dataframe is then grouped by column 'D' and the sums of column 'N' are collected. The index is reset and the amount in a three-day window is calculated.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', header=0)

df['D'] = pd.to_datetime(df['D'], errors='raise', format='%d/%m/%Y')
aaa = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('D')['N'].sum()).reset_index().rolling('3D', on='D', min_periods=1).sum()


print(aaa)
```

Output

```
           D     N
0 2021-06-01   6.0
1 2021-06-02   7.0
2 2021-06-03  14.0
3 2021-06-04  10.0
4 2021-06-05  15.0
5 2021-06-08   7.0
6 2021-06-09  19.0
```